# How to save settings in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

I installed unbuntu on virtualbox. The problem I have is that the settings don't get saved. Everytime I restart the server, it takes me to the main menu. (language settings etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you still have the CD image mounted in your Virtualbox.

Remove it here: [image]

Comment: One pic is worth a thousand words!
thanks for the help....it is working fine now!!